# Spring boot - Configure second datasource along with gloud gcp postgresql primary datasource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, google-cloud-sql

Setting up our Spring Boot project we have a database hosted on Google Cloud Gcp. We use Spring Data JPA to manipulate our database objects and it works great.

> application.yaml

```
spring:
  jpa:
database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
properties:
  hibernate:
    default_schema: {schema}
    dialect : org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
datasource:
  username: {username}
  password: {pwd}
cloud:
  gcp:
    sql:
      database-name: {dbname}
      instance-connection-name: {connection-name}
```

> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Using this Spring boot is able to autoconfigure the database connection and we are using Spring Data JPA to manipulate database objects.

This datasource is only used by our project, but our company has an Oracle database used by our ERP that I need to use. I figured I would use JdbcTemplate.

So I setup a Datasource and a JdbcTemplate linked to it :

> DatasourceConfiguration.java

```
@Bean(name = "dataSourceGenerix")
public DataSource dataSourceGenerix() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(generixDatasourceDriver);
    dataSource.setUrl(generixDatasourceUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(generixDatasourceUsername);
    dataSource.setPassword(generixDatasourcePassword);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateGenerix(@Qualifier("dataSourceGenerix") DataSource dataSourceGenerix) {
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = null;

    try(Connection conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSourceGenerix)) {
        jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSourceGenerix);
    } catch (SQLException | CannotGetJdbcConnectionException e) {
        log.error("{} {} : {}", Constantes.NO_DB_CONNECTION_GENERIX, generixDatasourceUrl, e.getMessage());
    }
    return jdbcTemplate;
}
```

With that setup, I can perform requests on this datasource.

But since I configures a Datasource explicitely, JPA now executes requests on that one and does not Autoconfigure my CLoud SQL datasource anymore.

I tried setting up a @Primary Datasource and explicitly configure parameters :

```
@Bean
@Primary
DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://google/{dbname}?cloudSqlInstance={instancename}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory");
    dataSource.setUsername({username});
    dataSource.setPassword({pwd});

    return dataSource;
}
```

Here's the logs at startup :

```
c.g.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory : Obtaining ephemeral certificate for Cloud SQL instance [{instancename}].
o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup      : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException:
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to retrieve information about Cloud SQL instance
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

So it seems like it cannot get to connect to Cloud SQL instance. I'm using the exact same parameters that I use in the application.yaml.

So how can I keep the autoconfiguration to Cloud GCP for my JPA needs, and add a second datasource for jdbc template ?

Comment: Why you do not do Autoconfiguration for any of those, you configure both manually and you inject each one where you need to use it?

Comment: The jdbctemplate datasource is manually configured already. As for Cloud SQL one, the manual config is precisely what i'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to these articles -> [spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases) or [using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7)

Basically while defining and initializing data source, you can specify the base package name of repositories which will use that particular data source.

E.g. in configuration class of oracle, you can specify base package of repository which will use oracle db and in Cloud GCP you can specify package containing repositories which will contact to Cloud GCP.

Comment: I came accross those, but I do not want to setup 2 JPA databases. My problem is that I've one JPA and one JDBC datasource. And more specifically the JPA one is a Cloud Gcp.
In the end my issue is how to manually configure the Cloud GCP one for JPA, what am I missing in my above configuration

Answer (score -1):

Check the repositories, please review this example.

https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

https://www.javaguides.net/2018/09/spring-boot-jpa-multiple-data-sources-example.html

Comment: This is not a proper answer to the question. Please post the solution here and do not refer to external sites for this. It also does not explain anything (here at least).